# Find the probability generating function $G(s)$ of this branching process.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, summation, random-variables, random-walk

Suppose that $X_n$ is size of the $n$th generation of a branching process started from a single individual, where each individual has a random number of children with probability mass function:

$$p(i)=pq^i\qquad i\geq0$$

where $q=p-1$. Find the probability generating function. Find the mean.

---

Would really appreciate if someone could direct me on how to find the mean, but the focus is how to find the pgf.

I know that $G_n(s)=G_{n-1}(G(s))=G(G_n(s))$. In other words, I need to find some $G(s)$ and then plug this into itself $n$-times, or guess some pattern. I have made very little headway.

$$G(s)=\sum^{\infty}_{i=0} p(i)s^i=\sum p (qs)^i$$

I assume that $|qs|<1$; therefore,

$$\sum p (qs)^i=\frac{p}{1-qs}.$$

However, upon plugging this into itself, I fail to notice anything meaningful. What am I missing, or what did I do wrong? How should I proceed?

Comment: This is one of the very few branching mechanisms such that $G_n$ can be computed explicitely. Messing around with $G=G_1$, $G_2$ and $G_3$ would have led you directly to the observation that $$G_n(s)=\frac{a_n-b_ns}{c_n-d_ns},$$ for some parameters $(a_n,b_n,c_n,d_n)$ solving $$a_{n+1}=a_n-pb_n\quad b_{n+1}=qa_n\quad c_{n+1}=c_n-pd_n\quad d_{n+1}=qc_n$$ with $(a_0,b_0,c_0,d_0)=(p,0,1,q)$. Thus, $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}-pqa_n$, whose elementary solutions are $p^n$ and $q^n$. Let $D_n=p^n-q^n$ and $D=p-q$, then, for every $n$, $a_n=pD_{n+1}/D$ which implies $b_n=pqD_n/D$. .../...

Comment: .../... Likewise, for every $n$, $c_n=D_{n+2}/D$ which implies $d_n=qD_{n+1}/D$. Finally, $$G_n(s)=p\frac{D_{n+1}-qD_ns}{D_{n+2}-qD_{n+1}s}.$$ Expanding the denominator as a geometric series yields the distribution of each $X_n$

Answer (score 0):

Denote the mean population for generation $n$ by $m_n$. Then $$m_1 = \mathbb E[X_1] = \lim_{s\uparrow 1}G'(s) = lim_{s\uparrow1}\frac{p(1-p)}{(1-(1-p)s)^2} = \frac{1-p}p.$$
Since $G_n(s) = G_{n-1}(G(s))$ (where $G_n(s)$ denotes $G$ composed $n$ times), we have
$$ G_n'(s) = G_{n-1}'(G(s))G'(s).$$
Hence
$$\begin{align*}
 m_n &= \lim_{s\uparrow 1} G_n'(s)\\ &= \lim_{s\uparrow1} G_{n-1}'(G(s))G'(s)\\
&= m_{n-1}m_1,\end{align*}$$
and from this recursion it is apparent that
$$ m_n = m^n = \left(\frac{1-p}p\right)^n.$$

In general determining the distribution of $X_n$ is very difficult. I don't know how to compute $G_n(s)$ either.